# Tried accessing nonexisting field (OmniAuth and Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I'm pretty new to rails and I've encountered an error while trying to initialize a user login using the omniauth-facebook gem. The error that reads on my browser is

```
{"message"=>"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (education_history) on node type (User)", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>100}: {"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (education_history) on node type (User)","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

However, the only education_history that exists in my project is a migration that I've done to add a column called education_history to my user...

In my `User`model, I have a method:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.birthday = auth.extra.raw_info.birthday
      user.education_history = auth.extra.raw_info.education
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expiry_date = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

which will be called when the user creates a new session...
.
And my `omniauth.rb` is

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, Rails.application.secrets.facebook_key, Rails.application.secrets.facebook_secret,
            scope: "email,user_birthday,user_work_history,,user_education_history,user_location", display: "popup", image_size: { width: "50", height: "50"},
            info_fields: "first_name,last_name,email,birthday,education"
end
```

and here's the `Schema` for my user

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expiry_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "birthday"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "education_history"   
end
```

I have no idea where to even begin debugging this error. Please help :(

Comment: The facebook user node doesn't have an education_history field. You should use education instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/